# form_for radio_button rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, form-for

How do I record this using form_for?

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="cc-selector">
        <%= f.radio_button :priorities, id: "yellow", name: "priorities", value: '1'%>
          <input id="a" type="radio" name="priorities" value=1/>
          <label class="priorities-cc yellow" for="a"></label>
          <input id="b" type="radio" name="priorities" value=2/>
          <label class="priorities-cc orange" for="b"></label>
          <input id="c" type="radio" name="priorities" value=3/>
          <label class="priorities-cc red" for="c"></label>
          <input id="c" type="radio" name="priorities" value=4/>
          <label class="priorities-cc fair" for="d"></label>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I tried, this don't work 
The other fields are stored in the database
    <%= f.radio_button :is_code, [a,1,b,2,c,3,d,4] %>

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I see just a `f.radio_button`, do you have a form, a submit button, a method where to receive that?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma  Yes. Other  fields are write in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see all the others `input` tags have an `integer` value, but in your `f.radio_button` you're setting the `value` as `'1'`, which is an string, you can check your validations or the data type that attribute is waiting to receive.

Try with:

```
<%= f.radio_button :priorities, 1, id: 'yellow', class: 'priorities-cc fair', for: 'd' %>
```

Note the second `value` or `parameter` for the `radio_button` is the value it'll take, the name will be controller and the attribute on brackets `controller[attribute]`.

Comment: does not work
How do I prescribe `class="priorities-cc fair" for="d"`?
This is important for css

Comment: On a `radio_button`?

Comment: Yes, I need to write using the form_for to get the same HTML identical to the one written

Comment: Glad to help (: